# Dompdf, no genera el PDF, solo carga por siempre?

Tags: laravel, pdf

Estoy utilizando **DOMpdf** para generar un **PDF** y luego guardarlo tanto en la base de datos como en la carpeta **Storage**, cuando genero el **PDF** de prueba, este se renderiza sin problemas, pero cuando trato de generar mi vista, este dura para siempre.

```
//esto genera el PDF sin problemas

$pdf = App::make('dompdf');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();

//Esto tarda por siempre

$html = View::make('miVista')->with('miVariable',$miVariable);
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);
    return $pdf->stream();
```

De esta forma también carga por siempre:

```
$data['miVariable'] = $miVariable;
$pdf = PDF::loadView('miVista',$data);
return $pdf->stream();
```

Cuando trato de generar el HTML o vista sin variables, me arroja error:

> unlink(C:\Users\miusuario\AppData\Local\Temp/912627fa8ee0eef3c82086a0d4462c2e): Permission denied

¿Qué se puede hacer? ¿Existe un mejor generador de PDF? He leído sobre **Mdpf** pero no se como integrarlo a **Laravel**.

**Edicion**

La version que instale fue la **v0.6.2**, y estoy utilizando **laravel 4.2**, lo instale siguiendo la instrucciones para las versiones 4.x del **dompd**, utiliznado el facade no funciona, y utilizando `download` en ves de `stream` tampoco funciona.

Comment: Cual version estas usando de Dompdf y de Laravel pk yo he probado con laravel 5.5 y "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.1", y perfectamente

Comment: Intenta usando el Facade y usa tambien la función download en ves de stream para que veas si da el mismo resultado.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido de `composer.json/lock` para reproducir exactamente tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

Para Laravel 4 debes instalar la versión 0.4, puedes reemplazar esta linea en tu composer y ejecutar **composer update**

```
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.4.*"
```

Y prueba usandolo así, yo asumo que tu vista esta en la carpeta **miVista** y esta se lla **index.blade.php**, tu haces la modificación pertinente:

```
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('miVista.index', $miVariable);
return $pdf->stream();
```